# Solution file appears in Target Folder when I publish a website project using File System publish method , in Visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm  new to dotnet. When I publish a website project in visual studio to a local folder, I see the build & publish are successfull but the solution file also appears in the folder. How to avoid this? Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is to look in the Package/Publish Web settings (in the web application project properties) and look for the "Items to deploy".

[image: No IMAGE]

For Web application projects, you typically build the project in Visual Studio or by using the ASP.NET batch compiler on a computer that is not the production IIS server. All code-behind class files and standalone class files in the project are compiled into a single assembly, which is then put in the Web application project's Bin folder. (The .aspx and .ascx files are compiled dynamically in a manner similar to what is done for Web site projects.)

For Web site projects, you do not have to manually compile the project. Web site projects are typically compiled dynamically by ASP.NET (on both the development computer and the production IIS server). You can choose between batch compilation mode, which typically produces one assembly per folder, and fixed compilation mode, which typically produces one assembly for each page or user control.

Comment: But I cannot find the option "Package/Publish" when I click on the properties of my websiteproject. Where to find that option in website project?.. Thanks in advance.